# EventMachine & Live Reload

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I am running a daemon which uses eventmachine. It must have 100% uptime, even while I re-deploy my code. So I am looking for zero-downtime deploys.

Is there a way to make EventMachine reload the code without losing connections? I thought about defining my `ConnectionHandler` in a separate file, then reloading it on `SIGHUP`:

```
Signal.trap("HUP") do
  load "#{path}/connection_handler.rb"
end
```

But this has disadvantages:

- It does not reload EventMachine itself (which is needed in case of gem updates)
- I don't know if this works.

Any advice?

Comment: see this link  http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/

Comment: see this also  https://github.com/mockko/livereload/wiki/Building

Answer (score 5):

Use a load balancer. On each deploy:

1. Take out half the machines off the load balancer.
2. Wait for them to finish handling their current requests.
3. Take down E.M. on those machines and deploy new code.
4. Put them back in the L.B. pool and repeat with the other half.

Comment: Nope. There is only one machine. Unicorn can do zero-downtime deploys (like this: http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn/). There must be a way for eventmachine to reload the code while running...

Comment: I realize that's not exactly what you had in mind, yes. Nevertheless from my experience it's a good thing to have. If you want something even close to 100% up time you'll need more than one machine anyway. If you only have one machine, you can run 2 EventMachine processes on different ports and use ngnix e.g. on port 80 to load balance between them.

Comment: +1 for this answer. You are aiming for 100% uptime but not being reasonable with your allotment of resources. What happens if your server crashes, power goes out, or some unforeseen event happens to bring the site down? There goes your 100% uptime on ANY server configuration. Given your options, the load balancer supporting multiple instances of the site is the preferred way to go.

Comment: See also [single point of failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure)